# How to pass in protocol Enum array to function in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a class that calls a function in another class using a protocol:

```
func calculateTableSize () {            
    // doing some stuff  
    // the call to the other function using the protocol
    summaryPresenter?.onCalculateTableSizeDone()     
}
```

I want to pass on a data array of type enum using this function:

```
class SummaryInteractor: SummaryScreenInteractorFunctionsProtocol {

    //sections
    enum Section: Int, CaseIterable {
        case header = 0, description, diagnoses, perscription, notes, addFaxHeadline,  addFax, addEmailHeadline, addEmails, givePermissionHeadline, selecAnswer, addNewEmail,addNewFax, removableText, headlineEmpty
    }

    var sectionData: [Section] = [
        .header
    ]

...
...
```

The problem is obviously i cannot add in my protocol this lines (which is what i want to achieve):

```
//what will be written in the presenterFromTheInteractor
protocol SummaryScreenInteractorProtocol {
    func onCalculateTableSizeDone(data: [Section])
}
```

because then the protocol (and all the other classes wouldn't know this new Enum types, of what is Selection.

So of course it shows error:

> Use of undeclared type 'Section'

How do I manage to pass that sectionData on to the rest of my functions?

Thank you

Comment: enum is not accessible due to internal access. better put enum outside of the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your enum isn't accessible from protocol since it is embedded inside another class. You have two options

1. Move enum outside

   ```
   enum Section {}

   class SummaryInteractor {}
   ```
2. Specify location of enum: `SummaryInteractor.Section`

   ```
   func onCalculateTableSizeDone(data: [SummaryInteractor.Section])
   ```

Comment: can you give me some code examples of where do you mean to move the enum outside ? 
or how to specify location of the enum Summary.interactor.section ? , preferable on how to put the enum outside

Comment: Thank you Robert, what do you think is the better option to do ?

Comment: @ChiefMadog we should ask somebody cleverer then me, but in your case I think there is no difference, they're just declared on different places. I think it depends on your code organization.